# Naming suggestion for a method - checkSignature or isSignatureValid or something else?

Tags: methods, naming-conventions

I have a method that checks the signature of a request is valid.
The method returns a boolean:
_ true: valid signature
_ false: signature is not valid

I am not sure about the best name for it (maybe also because I am not an English native speaker).
I am not sure among:
_ checkSignature
_ isSignatureValid

Which one do you think is better and why or maybe you have a better suggestion.

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

isSignatureValid( ... ).  It tells you what the method is going to return, which is nice.  Also, it doesn't make a promise one way or another as far as caching goes (checkSignature implies to me that you will do all the math to check the signature when I call it, and you might not need to repeat all that work).

Answer (score 1):

I prefer

```
hasValidSignature()
```

since `isSignatureValid()` doesn't semantically make sense because the request isn't a signature, it *has* a signature.  I suppose you're going to be using this in an `if` statement so doesn't this make more sense?

```
if (request.hasValidSignature()) {
    ...
}
```

Furthermore, if you want to check if `request` is valid *itself*, then this would be more appropriate

```
if (request.isValid()) {
    ...
}
```